# search record from table depending upon two conditions

Tags: mysql

Consider a table abc having two columns device_date and device_time (both varchar mysql)

```
            device_date    device_time
             1-1-2014       0:0:00
             1-1-2014       10:0:00
             2-1-2014       0:0:00
             3-1-2014       5:0:00
             1-1-2014       0:0:00
             1-1-2014       0:0:00
```

Now I want to find to records that are having device date *>=* 2-1-2014 and device_time *>=*  0:0:00

but the result set is having all the records having device_time *>=* 0:0:00 
The result set should be only contain

```
     
             2-1-2014       0:0:00
             3-1-2014       5:0:00
```

But The result set is

```
             1-1-2014       0:0:00
             1-1-2014       10:0:00
             2-1-2014       0:0:00
             2-1-2014       5:0:00
             4-1-2014       0:0:00
             5-1-2014       0:0:00
```

query is like select * from  where device_time >= '0:0:00' AND  device_date >= '1-1-2014'

Comment: You're using `>=` which means "larger than or equal". You should use `=` which means "equals"

Comment: Even if i use = i am not getting the desired result

Comment: The following query should give you the desired result: `select * from where device_time = '0:0:00' AND device_date = '1-1-2014'`.

Comment: This is mysql. These are not dates.

Comment: as @Strawberry noted these aren't how you should store dates in any table. also if you would please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to properly ask a question it has many tips including formatting queries / tables and what you should provide in a question

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert it to a date and then do your comparrison on it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( device_date , "%d-%m-%Y" ) , "%Y/%m/%d" ) > '2014/01/01'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e5139/2)

EDIT:
if you want to compare on the time although it will always be greater than or equal to 00:00:00 you can use the same method.

```
STR_TO_DATE(device_time, '%h:%i:%s')
```

Comment: It is not related to date_format search also include the device_time column

Comment: @user3194123 you say you want it to be a date that is greater than January first... and the time isn't needed unless somehow you are storing negative time.

Comment: @user3194123 I posted a working demo for you to use.

Comment: @user3194123 I edited with the conversion for the time.

Comment: @user3194123 dont forget to accept the answer!! it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

You can search like

```
select * from table where device_date='1-1-2014' AND device_time='0:0:00';
```